# Using Oracle driver in Karaf with Apache Camel SQL Component

Tags: java, sql, osgi, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I am trying to use Oracle jdbc 6 driver in Apache Karaf buy I am facing some difficulties. Particularly, I am trying to make use of the driver to access my database through the Camel SQL Component.

My blueprint file looks like this:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="dataSourceName" value="XXXXX" />
        <property name="TNSEntryName" value="XXXXX" />
        <property name="DriverType" value="XXXXX" />
        <property name="user" value="XXXXX" />
        <property name="password" value="XXXXX" />
    </bean>

    <!-- configure the Camel SQL component to use the JDBC data source -->
    <bean id="sql" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="properties" class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
        <property name="location" value="file:${karaf.home}/etc/sqlStatements.properties" />
    </bean>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="metis123">
            <from uri="timer:foo?period=5000" />
            <to uri="sql:{{sql.check_rwos_update}}" id="sqlCheckRwosUpdate" />
            <to uri="log:com.hveiga?showAll=true" />
        </route>
    </camelContext> 
</blueprint>
```

When I am placing my file into the `deploy` directory in Karaf I am getting the following exception:

```
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to instantiate components
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/sql/DataSource
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.sql.DataSource not found by oracle.ojdbc6 [131]
```

So it seems it is a problem with the oracle driver not being able to find some class. I have *osgified* the oracle jar using the apache-felix maven plugin but maybe I am doing something wrong and the MANIFEST.MF file is missing something.

Any idea what I could be missing?

Comment: Can you explain what you do to install your blueprint. Starting from a fresh karaf (which version). You surely install the oracle driver somehow.

Comment: To install my blueprint I just drop the xml and the oracle driver jar files into the deploy directory. Karaf version is 2.3.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my issue by adding to the `MANIFEST.MF` the following line:

```
Import-Package: javax.sql, javax.naming, javax.management, org.ietf.jgss
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in my [karaf db tutorial](http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2012/01/13/Apache+Karaf+Tutorial+Part+6+-+Database+Access).

Simply dropping the db driver probably does not work. I describe there to use the wrap: protocol of pax url. This way the drivers are bundled with bnd and default settings on the fly. So this might already give you a working system. For production use it is better though to bundle the drivers using a maven project like bgossit described. You will find a lot of examples for this at [servicemix bundles](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/servicemix/smx4/bundles/trunk/).

Answer (score 1):

I had to do similar wrapping of an Oracle driver into a bundle using Maven. This is what I had that may help:

Oracle bundle:

```
Export-Package: oracle.jdbc, oracle.jdbc.driver
Import-Package: !javax.*, !oracle.*
```

Other bundles that refer to it just had `Import-Package: *` and Maven filled in the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried but I got: `org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle oracle.ojdbc6 [131]: Unable to resolve 131.1: missing requirement [131.1] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=!javax.*)`

Comment: Are you using the maven bundle plugin ? I expected it would result in settings such as "Ignore-Package: javax.sql" in the generated manifest.

Comment: There is no "Ignore-Package" in the Manifest file for the oracle jar file.

Comment: OK that's interesting. You could try put them in as Ignore-Package entries instead of Import-Package entries with exclamation mark, or abandon this idea if you like, I wasn't sure it would work for you too but thought it worth a try...

Comment: I will give it a try and thank you for your help. Tonight I will keep investigating about this and I will post the solution if I find it. Thanks again.